# In an xpage get a picture from a database where I don't have access to (acl)

Tags: xpages

Is there a way for a web user of an xpages based webpage to be able to show (read mode only) a document that is in a database where annonymous doesn't has acces to in the acl.
If I had access I could get the the document with for example : 
`https://servername/otherdatabase.nsf/O/"+thisid+"/$FILE/"+thisdocument`

I guess it must be possible with SessionAsSigner , but how ?

Secondly is there a way for this user to see a view from a database where anonymous doesn't has acces to ? How can I set this up ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially this is impossible.

You could construct the URL using sessionAsSigner but when the user tries to access the document / image they will get an unauthorized exception.

The only way you could display the view of data would be to read the contents of the view into a scoped variable (or bean) using sessionAsSigner and then display a repeat control that references the data from the scoped variable instead of the view directly.

The larger question is why you want to do this. If Anonymous can't have access to the database in question then there's a good reason for this. Another alternative would be to think about using $PublicAccess flags on the documents / views that you want to give Anonymous access to. Then on the ACL, as long as Anonymous can read public data then they can still have no access to the database.

Matt

Comment: Matt, I don't want to give access to the database as some data in the database is not for public access.How do I set the $PublicAccess flag on some documents when a field contains a certain value ? (ps thanks for your session at the BLUG !)

Comment: You can simply add a computed text field to the documents called $PublicAccess, compute it to "1" if you want public access on the document and "0" if not. Remember that any view that you want the users to access the document through will also need to have Public Access set on its security as well.

Comment: Do I understand this well ? When I set the view "Available to public access users" those users will only see the documents with $PublicAccess flag set to "1". They won't see the other documents ?

Comment: As long as Anonymous has the Read Public Documents set and the view that the documents are being accessed via is also set to allow public access then yes.

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to use an XAgent; for example, set the `beforeRenderResponse` event to the following:

```
var fileDb = sessionAsSigner.getDatabase((param.server || ""), param.path);
var fileDocument = fileDb.getDocumentByUNID(param.id);
var attachment = fileDocument.getAttachment(param.filename);
var inputStream = attachment.getInputStream();
var response = facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
/* The following MIME type is generic, should work for all image types;
If you know what type the image will be, set a more specific MIME type */
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
var outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
com.acme.xsp.util.StreamUtil.copyStream(inputStream, outputStream);
inputStream.close();
outputStream.close();
attachment.recycle();
fileDocument.recycle();
facesContext.responseComplete();
```

`com.acme.xsp.util.StreamUtil` refers to a Java convenience class for pipelining one stream to another:

```
public class StreamUtil {
    public static void copyStream(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
}
```

So instead of linking your image tag directly to the attachment, it would look something like this:

```
<xp:image url="/download.xsp?server=ACME01&amp;path=images.nsf&amp;id=OU812&amp;filename=photo.jpg" />
```

This approach would also afford you other options: logging how many times a given file is accessed, referer URL (in case you want to implement the "no hotlinking" image replacement you sometimes see when searching Google for images), or really anything you want.

As a specific example, about a decade ago I saw a coworker implement a basic in-house equivalent to Google Analytics that even worked on browsers that didn't support JavaScript because he used this technique for the company logo on every page of the site: instead of linking directly to the logo JPG, he linked to a PHP file that grabbed IP, referer, user agent, etc., wrote all of the metadata out to a MySQL database, then finally streamed the bytes of the logo to the browser. This is obviously outside the scope of what it sounds like you're trying to accomplish, but I figured you might find it interesting that this type of use case is rather simple now in XPages.

Comment: Read the whole answer, Sven. ;) "com.acme.xsp.util.StreamUtil refers to a Java convenience class for pipelining one stream to another:"

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Always reading code, not the words between ;-)

Answer (score 4):

This is possible using sessionAsSigner and for instance a repeat. If the XPage is in the same database, then make sure to mark the XPage as available for public access. The follwing simple example will display content from the view columns and an image from the document:

```
<xp:repeat id="protectedView" rows="15" removeRepeat="true" var="rowEntry" disableOutputTag="true">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
        var thisDb = sessionAsSigner.getDatabase(database.getServer(), database.getFilePath());
        var aView = thisDb.getView("protectedView");
        return staffView.getAllEntries(); // return collection of docs
    }]]></xp:this.value>
        <xp:text>
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(1)}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:text>
        <xp:br />
        <xp:text>
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:rowEntry.getColumnValues().elementAt(2)}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:text>
        <xp:br />
        <xp:inputRichText id="inputRichText1" readonly="true">
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                // wrap NotesDocument into NotesXspDocumenet to easily display picture
                wrapDocument(rowEntry.getDocument()).getValue("Picture");}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:inputRichText>
</xp:repeat>
```

I use [the wrapDocument XSnippet](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=wrap-notesdocument-into-notesxspdocument) to convert NotesDocument into NotesXspDocument.

Comment: Is it save working this way ? It seems I can connect to views that don't have public access marked. I can also open documents that don't have the $PublicAccess flag set. I only need to set public access read public documents on the database.

Comment: Correct, you need to give anonymous public access (and mark the XPage for public access). Is it safe? It's an option like many others - and how it's used, depends on the developer :-)